# Ruby While Issue

Tags: ruby

I'm just learning Ruby, and I'm a bit confused at the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

while line = gets
  if line == 'x'
    puts 'You pressed x'
  end
end
```

It doesn't seem to print anything if x is entered. Am I doing the comparison correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gets` returns entered text along with the linebreak. Try this:

```
while line = gets.chomp
  # the rest is the same
end
```

[`String#chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) removes such characters (`\n`, `\r`, `\r\n`) from a string.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't mentioned in the book I'm reading (Pragmatic Ruby 1.9). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you type x then press `enter` you're adding `\n` and/or `\r`.

To fix this you have to compare

`if line.chomp == 'x'`

Your loop should work and print out "You pressed x"